# HTMLCollection object extensions?

Tags: javascript, dom

I found that HTMLOptionsCollection object inherits properties and methods from HTMLCollection.

```
HTMLOptionsCollections->HTMLCollection->Object->null
```

Is there any other type that also inherits HTMLCollection?

Comment: just traversed in the prototype chain , starting from HTMLOptionsCollection object using Object.getPrototypeOf(..) till we get the null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find other DOM interfaces which should inherit from HTMLCollection in the HTML5 spec:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#collections-0

However, these objects are not necessarly actually implemented in current browsers.